# Using a dictionary along with geoprocessing tools?

Tags: arcpy, for-loop, dictionary

I am new to python and trying to create a script that will select specific parcels from a large parcel layer. Is it possible to create a dictionary with the names of the parcels as the key and the query used to find the parcels as the value and input those into a arcpy.Select_analysis with a for loop to loop through the dictionary? What would be the best way to set this up?

example

```
Import arcpy
import os  #importing operating system functions
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:\gis\python\other\parcels.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

properties{'johns pizza':"MUN in ('1323') and BLOCK in ('168') and LOT in ('20')",'chinese palace':"MUN in ('1326') and BLOCK in ('12') and LOT in ('100')"}`

for key in properties:
    arcpy.Select_analysis("parcels", key, value)
```

Comment: Learn how to loop over dictionaries in Python. stackoverflow is the place to look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops

Comment: That workflow seems unnecessary. Why not simply apply the SQL expression in the `Select_analysis()` tool?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [syntax section](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/select.htm#GUID-7A36E319-BD9F-4A66-94BC-67297E2D6165) of the Select tool it explains the parameters of the tool. Parameter 2 is the output feature class (what is you KEY from your dictionary) and parameter 3 is the where clause (what is value from your dictionary).

Your output featureclass name is invalid for a geodatabase, it cannot have spaces in it. Suggest you read this [Defining FeatureClass properties page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/feature-classes/defining-feature-class-properties.htm).